# Indexing an NVARCHAR(MAX) column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When I define a column as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, I can't index that column. But I certainly can't define the column as `NVARCHAR(4000)` since I assume the data string will be longer sometimes.

Can anyone suggest how to index the column with `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data definition or is it possible to increase the length from 4000 to more?

Comment: use a hashbyte on your column and index it - and no, you cant index nvarchar(max) it doesnt make sense

Comment: With that amount of text, are you sure you're not looking for `full text indexing`?

Comment: What would you be hoping to get out of indexing a value greater than 4000 characters? Would you want to search for exact equality matches or something else?

Comment: No the field i wanted to index was a combination of multiple field(like multiple addresses, addr line 1..7, city, country etc) from another table inserted into it for matching/finding percentage of match record purpose. I really thing , it won't exceed 900 bytes but just i was wondering if it could be possible somehow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. You have either nvarchar(4000) or nvarchar(max). Nothing in between
2. Maximum length of the index key column(s) together is 900 bytes, so you can't index nvarchar(4000) either (which is 8000 bytes)

Personally, I can't see why you need to index nvarchar(max).
Are you seriously going to search for strings up to 1GB long?

Anyway, your only option is to use [HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql) in a persisted computed column.
You create a hash of the column, and index the HASH.

Note, depending on what version you may not be able to hash nvarchar(max)

> For SQL Server 2014 and earlier, allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes.

SQL Server 2016 code example that also enforces uniqueness
The SHA2_512 hash gives the least chance of collision. For a sufficiently large table a weaker hash like MD4 will hit the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HashExample (
    SomeID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    SomeLongText nvarchar(MAX) NULL,
    SomeHash AS HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', SomeLongText) PERSISTED
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_SomeHash ON dbo.HashExample(SomeHash) WHERE SomeLongText IS NULL
GO

INSERT dbo.HashExample (SomeLongText) VALUES ('Row 1'), ('Row 2')
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.HashExample
GO

DECLARE @LookFor nvarchar(MAX) = 'Row 3'
SELECT * FROM dbo.HashExample WHERE SomeHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @LookFor)
SET @LookFor = 'Row 2'
SELECT * FROM dbo.HashExample WHERE SomeHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @LookFor)
GO
```

Note, you can't have LIKE searches. Only `=` or `<>`

Comment: Just my thoughts :) Great answer

Comment: actually the field i am trying to index is a combination of multiple field for matching and deciding percentage of match. I know it won't exceed 900 bytes , but for safer side, i was wondering if there is any way to index a max length column. I got the point you made and this is really a nice explanation. Thank you.